# Error Using double Brackets vs single brackets in for loop in R

Tags: r, slice

I am trying to run this code to find the mean of each column.

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10),
  c = rnorm(10),
  d = rnorm(10)
)

output <- vector("double", length = ncol(df))
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  output[i] <- mean(df[i])   
}
output
```

I am getting error for not using df[[i]] though df[1] is slicing the data frame and returning the result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. You might want to try `colMeans(df)`.  You need to specify  `mean(df[,i]) ` instead of  `mean(df[i]) `

Comment: Check the difference in output of `mean(df[1])` vs `mean(df[[1]])`. Also go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el